# Aggregating or concatenating a list of ints into a string in a functional way

Tags: c#, reduce

I've a list of integers that I want to concatenate in a functional way, something on the line of `reduce` function.

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>{1, 2, 3};
```

The expected output is

```
(1)(2)(3)
```

I came across this snippet to do aggregation in a functional way, so I attempted.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Aggregate("", (acc, x) => "(" + x + ")");
```

**Attempt**

```
ids.GetRange(0, ids.Count).Aggregate((x, y) => "(" + x + ")");
```

**Error**

```
Cannot convert type string to int
```

---

**Edit**

fixing

```
ids.GetRange(0, ids.Count).Aggregate((acc, x) => acc + "(" + x + ")");
```

Comment: Is something like `"(" + string.Join(")(", ids) + ")"` an acceptable solution? The only thing wrong in your code with Aggregate seems to be that it doesn't add the already accumulated value to the result (`(acc, x) => "(" + x + ")");` -> `"(acc, x) => acc + "(" + x + ")");`).

Comment: Why not simply `ids.Select(x => "(" + x + ")");`?

Comment: Please see my edits, I don't want to use `string.Join`, looking for an `accumulator` based approach.

Comment: `ids.Aggregate("", (x,y) => x + "(" + y ")");` seems to be what you are looking for - you need the first parameter to specify you are aggregating on a `string` type

Comment: `Select` is LINQ based, and `Aggregate` is a vanilla version of reduce, right?

Comment: What "vanilla" means? `Aggregate` is extension method in `System.Linq` namespace.  https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Don't forget to ask a question when you post a question; there's no question in this post, just a story about how you wrote some wrong code and got an error. What's your question?

Comment: can you please update the link to use english version.

Comment: @AppDeveloper sorry, en-us url is here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @EricLippert I kinda mentioned under expected output, I'll be specific next time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting comes from the type of the aggregate result being deduced to `int` (as you are using a `List<int>`), because you didn't specify a `seed` value. Adding this seed as in the first example you posted fixes the error.
Further you need to use both the so far accumulated value (`x` in your code) and the current value (`y` in your code):
`ids.Aggregate("", (x, y) => x + "(" + y + ")");`
Note that I also dropped the call to `GetRange` as you are iterating over all values of the `List` anyway

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform the the `int` values to `string` before you can concatenate them in a `string`. But your attempt would result in '1(2)(3)' because we take the first item (but we wont call the function for it), call the aggregate function to add the 2nd item, then call the function again to add the 3rd to the previous result and so on. Have a look at the source of `Aggregate`. it's a simple loop which starts at the second element and loops till the end:

```
        TSource source1 = enumerator.Current;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
          source1 = func(source1, enumerator.Current);
        return source1;
```

so this will fix the compile error of your code but will not deliver the result you hoped for.

```
ids.GetRange(0, ids.Count).Select(id => id.ToString()).Aggregate((acc, x) => acc + "(" + x + ")");
```

a better aproach would to prepare the single values and then join the strings or if you need to use Aggregate you could use it too. But be aware that aggregate takes the first item and calls the function only for the 2nd and following items to add them.

```
string.Join("", ids.Select(id => $"({id})"));

ids.Select(id => $"({id})").Aggregate((aggregate, id) => aggregate + id);
```